# Fast setdiff for each combinations of rows of two data.frames in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, set-difference

I am working with some experimental data in which I need to compare reference and treated data together. I got two data.frames and the goal is to create all the combinations of rows of two data.frames and check if setdiff of two rows is greater than 10 and save the row id to a list of there is a matching.

I prepared a general solution that looks like:

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
df1 <- data.frame(a = rpois(150, 2), b = rpois(150, 2))
df2 <- data.frame(a = rpois(150, 10), b = rpois(150, 14))
out <- vector("list", nrow(df1))
names(out) <- rownames(df1)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df1))) {
  map <- NULL
  for (j in seq_len(nrow(df2))) {
    if (all(setdiff(c(df2[j, ]), c(df1[i, ])) > 10)) {
      map <- c(map, j)
    }
  }
  out[[i]] <- map
}
```

The problem is that this is a very slow solution for really big data frames (more than 30 000 rows). I am not sure how to speed up this for loop. I will be grateful for any propositions.

Answer (score 0):

In the next way you get both indices `i` (`rowname...1`) (row number for `df1`) and `j` (`rowname...4`) (row number for `df2`)

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- expand_grid(df1 %>% rownames_to_column(),df2 %>% rownames_to_column(), .name_repair = "universal")
df$a <- df[[5]] - df[[2]]
df$b <- df[[6]] - df[[3]]
df[which(df$a > 10 & df$b > 10),c(1,4)]

# A tibble: 2,194 × 2
   rowname...1 rowname...4
   <chr>       <chr>      
 1 1           47         
 2 1           97         
 3 2           47         
 4 2           97         
 5 2           111        
 6 2           117        
 7 3           8          
 8 3           11         
 9 3           13         
10 3           14         
# … with 2,184 more rows
```